# Вывод уменьшенных копий изображений на экран

Tags: php

Для создания фотогалереи небоходимо изначально вывести на экран уменьшенные копии фотографий, а затем, по выбору  пользователя,  - их обычный размер. Для вывода в браузер с помощью тэга `<img>` уменьшенные копии должны находится на жестком диске. Как обойти этот момент? Возможно ли динамически уменьшать фотографии и выводить их в браузере без сохранения на диске? `header('Content-Type: image/*')` не  прокатит, потому что на странице уже куча информации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, сжимать изображения при каждом запросе не правильно.

Необходимо при загрузке сохранять несколько изображений с разным размером.

Для резки и сжатия изображений советую прекрасную библиотеку [**AcImage**](http://true-coder.ru/php/toolkit-dlya-resajza-i-kropa-izobrazhenij-na-php.html).

Comment: Насколько я понял, помимо фотографий нормального размера, должен постоянно существовать каталог с уменьшенными копиями?

Comment: За Aclmage спасибо!

Comment: @Deus, да..

Comment: Готов поспорить) если сервер не нагружен то для экономии места может иметь смысл динамически уменьшать фоты)

Comment: Хорошо, как динамически уменьшенную фоту вывести в браузер без использования header()?

Comment: на это вам яндекс ответит лучше меня, и даже с примерами кода http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=php+image+resize&lr=39

Comment: и кстати вы не поверите но даже так можно <img url="/image.php?id=$id"> а в image.php задавайте нужные хидеры(которые не помешают страничке нормаль отработать ибо грузятся браузером как отдельный файл со своими хидерами)